# Браузер не принимает Cookie

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js, axios, laravel-5.6

Имеются два приложения:

- Laravel 5.6 - PHP 7.1, Apache, `http://api.domain.com`
- Vue2 - Node 8.11.2, `http://test.domain.com:8080`

Пытаюсь запросом к api получить Cookie в ответ.

Код на клиенте:

```
axios.get('//api.domain.com/api/testget')
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

Код на сервере (api routes):

```
Route::get('/testget', function () {
    return response('ok')
        ->cookie('name', 'value', 10, '/', '.domain.com', false, false)
});
```

Header присутствует:
`Set-Cookie: name=value; expires=Wed, 06-Jun-2018 15:31:51 GMT; Max-Age=600; path=/; domain=.domain.com`
Но `document.cookie` возвращает `""`, на панели разработчика в браузере в разделе Application->Cookies тоже ничего нету. Ошибок в консоли нету.

Response Headers полностью:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 06 Jun 2018 15:23:44 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://admin.domain.com:8080
Vary: Origin
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 58
Set-Cookie: name=value; expires=Wed, 06-Jun-2018 15:33:44 GMT; Max-Age=600; path=/; domain=.domain.com
Content-Length: 2
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможно, в том, что поддомен не имеет никакого права влиять на родительский домен? Это как если бы сайт example.github.io вмешался в работу сайта github.io - небезопасно же

Comment: @andreymal повторил те же действия, но уже из-под `domain.com` - та же проблема...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
axios.get('//api.domain.com/api/testget', {withCredentials: true}) //<---
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

Сервер должен устанавливать соответственный Header при отправке ответа. [Полезная библиотека](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors).
Конфиг:

```
return [
    ...
    'supportsCredentials' => true, //<---
    ...
]
```